# JSQMessages keyboard not pushing up view

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When I go to type a message into my JSQMessagesViewController, the view is not being pushed up when the keyboard appears. [image]

I can't send a message and I can't see the message I'm typing.

I don't even see any code in my VC that would be causing this / that would have changed this so I don't know where to start looking or what code to supply. I've downloaded examples using JSQMessages and I feel like this is just built in functionality behind the scenes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have viewDidAppear/viewDidDissapear being used you have to use

```
super.viewDidAppear(true)
```

and

```
super.viewDidDissapear(true)
```

also called respectively.

Adding those in fixed the issue.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I forgot to call super's viewDidAppear. Oops.